# Default values for panelizer and fieldable panel panes

Tags: panels

I have a template being applied to a node with a few different fieldable panel panes on it. I can create a new piece of content and it's page will load with the template applied and all of the FPP's right where they should be.

Say I make 10 pieces of content and they all have that same template. If I go to one of them and add something to an FPP on it and then save as custom that FPP will be modified the same way on all 10 pages. If I use the inline editor and remove the panel with content, save as custom, and then add that panel back it will be empty.

If I have a blank panels template and go to all 10 pages one at a time and add the FPPs to them and save them each as custom then the FPPs will stay unique.

I need to be able to load the complete template with the content panes already there but have them all be empty when the page is initially made.

Is there anyway to assign a panel a default value of nothing?

Answer (score 1):

The methods hook_entity_insert() / hook_entity_update() don't check whether an entity has dedicated panelizer settings or not and just always saves the panelizer object found for it. Which can be the defaults of course.
The attached patch looks worse than it actually is. It basically introduces the property entity_custom_panelizer which indicates if a panelizer setting is dedicated to the entity or not.
And the hooks hook_entity_insert() / hook_entity_update() only save the settings into the panelizer_entity if the flag is set.
I really hope I didn't miss something but first smoke-tests look promising.